# Ambiguity about passive in my textbook

Tags: phrases, prepositions, ambiguity, prepositional-phrases, passive-voice

In my textbook, it said

> "In an active sentence we need to include the agent as subject; using
>   a passive allows us to *omit the agent by leaving out the
>   prepositional phrase with **by***"

Ex:
Jackson threw me *into the dungeon* 
I was thrown *into the dungeon*

The prepositional phrase is still intact, so why does it say "*leaving out the prepositional phrase*"?

Comment: Because it **can** be left out: "I was thrown into the dungeon" does not state the agent.

Comment: But the prepositional phrase is still there.. What am I missing here?

Comment: The "prepositional phrase with by" is the ***by*** phrase, which they have left out instead of stating "I was thrown into the dungeon by Jackson".

Comment: A simpler example to start with would be: Marshall bowled Boycott. ==> Boycott was bowled.

Comment: @AndrewLeach I still don't really get it, but you seem like you know what you're saying. So I guess I'll meditate on it later haha.. Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: It doesn't say  "leaving out the prepositional phrase"; it says  "leaving out the prepositional phrase **with by** " (which it leaves out in the example 'I was thrown into the dungeon').

Comment: Identifying constituents in fact instead of by vague description is a good start to any syntactic analysis.

Comment: Ah, at last... I get it now lol

Comment: @JohnLawler Thanks for the tip, I'll be sure to do some more googling on syntactic analysis later. Do you have any more tips for me to look into?

Comment: Just on the curious side, do native English speaker find it easy to comprehend the sentence I wrote just now, or is it easy only for academics? lol

Comment: Start with [logic](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/logicguide.pdf) and go on to [the verb phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf). After that the only real problem is identifying the remains of dead subordinate clauses and how they're related.

Comment: Some academics are native English speakers too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In an active sentence we need to include the agent as subject; using a passive allows us to omit the agent by leaving out the prepositional phrase with *by*.

- Active: Jackson throws me into the dungeon.
- Passive: I was thrown into the dungeon **by Jackson.**
- Agentless passive: I was thrown into the dungeon.

The “prepositional phrase with *by*” is the phrase starting *by* which identifies the agent. In converting an active sentence to a passive, the agent is available and can be included as in the second example here.

The agent can be omitted if we leave out the phrase starting *by* (see the third example).

The textbook is **not** talking about the “into the dungeon” prepositional phrase, because that is not “the prepositional phrase with *by*”. It can be simplified using Edwin Ashworth's examples:

- Active: Marshall bowled Boycott.
- Passive:  Boycott was bowled by Marshall.
- Agentless passive:  Boycott was bowled.